# Is it possible to get a list of the UID of all users in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there anywhere in Firebase where I could see a list of all the unique identifiers that have been assigned to all the users? I user an email as the identifier and I need to see a list of all emails that are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to do it, as explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).